# How to create a osg::Image object in Android?

Tags: openscenegraph, osgearth

On iOS/windows I can create a osg::Image object by this:

```
     osg::ref_ptr<osg::Image> icon = osgDB::readRefImageFile(filePath);
```

the filePath param could be the "Resource/a.png", which is a relative path in the project. but this could not work in Android. I also tried using an absolute path like：

```
"/storage/emulated/0/res/a.png"
```

the path was the full sd card path to a.png, but didn't work either.

The Image object was used to be the icon of a osgEarth::Annotation::PlaceNode:

```
osg::ref_ptr<osg::Image> icon = osgDB::readRefImageFile(filePath);
node->setIconImage(icon.get());
```

On iOS, the icon could be displayed, but didn't display on Android. I am certain the problem was the osg::Image object didn't create properly on Android.

I appreciate very much if anyone could help. Thanks.

Comment: When you say it "didn't work", can you give details about what went wrong?

Did you assign your app the "Storage" permission in order to access that path?

Comment: hi @XenonofArcticus, thanks for replying. I edit the question for more details so you can know what I mean.

Comment: @XenonofArcticus the app has the "Storage" permission.